# Pytorch - extracting predicted values to an array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm a new pytorch user and moderate experience with Tensorflow/Keras. The pytorch examples are fantastic. I've worked through the demand forecasting lab using the Temporal Fusion Transform (https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/stallion.html).

All makes sense but haven't figured out how to save the predicted values in notebook section #20 to a numpy array.

Section #20,
`*new_raw_predictions, new_x = best_tft.predict(new_prediction_data, mode="raw", return_x=True)*`

I see the values in the tensors, *print(new_raw_predictions)* ,
like this --
*{'prediction': tensor([[[3.4951e+00, 1.7341e+01,     2.7446e+01,  ..., 6.3175e+01,
9.0240e+01, 1.2589e+02],
[1.1698e+01, 2.3643e+01, 3.3291e+01,  ..., 6.6374e+01,
9.1148e+01, 1.3173e+02],

I've seen some similar questions asked here but none seem to work. All attempts result in a similar error so I'm missing something fundamental about pytorch and the output tensor; I always get 'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute new_raw_predictions'

A few examples of what's been tried:
`*new_raw_predictions.cpu().numpy() new_raw_predictions.detach().cpu().numpy() new_raw_predictions.numpy()*`

Goal is to save the predicted output so I can compare changes to the model. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you've created your model, because pytorch can return values however you specify. In your case, it looks like it returns a dictionary, of which 'prediction' is a key. You can convert to numpy using the command you supplied above, but with one change:

```
preds = new_raw_predictions['prediction'].detach().cpu().numpy()
```

of course if it's not on the GPU you don't need to use `.detach().cpu()`, just `.numpy()`

Comment: Nailed it!!! Thanks. I wasn't thinking in 'python' terms.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Could you please accept this answer so others can find it easily? :)